# similar syntax for multiple objects

Tags: excel, form-control, vba

I have multiple spinbuttons on my userform and I want to put the same codes on each one of them,

```
Me.TextBox1.Value = Me.TextBox1.Value - 1

If Me.TextBox1.Value = 0 Then
    Me.TextBox1.Value = 12
End If

If Me.TextBox1.Value < 10 Then
    Me.TextBox1.Value = "0" & Me.TextBox1.Value
End If
```

but is there a simplified way rather than putting multiple blocks on multiple spinbuttons, and just group them all together in one block?

Answer (score 2):

Put hte bulk of the code into its own Sub procedure and pass the object to it from the 'handler' sub of each button.

```
Private Sub button1_Click()
    allSpin Me.TextBox1
End Sub

Private Sub button2_Click()
    allSpin Me.TextBox2
End Sub

Private Sub button3_Click()
    allSpin Me.TextBox3
End Sub

Sub allSpin(ByRef tb As Object)
    With tb
        .Value = .Value - 1
        If .Value = 0 Then
            .Value = 12
        ElseIf .Value < 10 Then
            .Value = "0" & .Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

That is pretty generalized and tbh, I doubt if it would work straight out of the box but I hope it is enough to give you an idea on how it works.

That last sub may be better like this,

```
Sub allSpin(ByRef tb As Object)
    With tb
        If Int(.Value) = 1 Then
            .Value = 12
        Else
            .Value = Format(Int(.Value) - 1, "00")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry for not giving any words for almost a week now, just had an Easter holiday and just got back to work, will be trying out the code in a bit, thank you.

Comment: thanks you two, I tried mashing your codes together and it's working, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code refers to Textbox.value as an integer.
I think what you might be wanting to do is to get the spin buttons to wrap from 0 to 12 when clicking down, and perhaps stop at 12 when clicking up. Assuming the SpinButtons are SpinButton1, SpinButton2, SpinButton3 and there are related textboxes of the same number:
Try this

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
  SpinUpdate
End Sub
Private Sub SpinButton2_Change()
  SpinUpdate
End Sub
Private Sub SpinButton3_Change()
  SpinUpdate
End Sub
Private Sub SpinUpdate()
Dim StrI As String
  StrI = Right(ActiveControl.Name, 1)
  With Me.Controls("SpinButton" & StrI)
    If .Value = 0 Then
        .Value = 12
    End If
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & StrI).Text = Format(.Value, "00")
  End With
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
Dim i As Integer
  For i = 1 To 3
    With Me.Controls("SpinButton" & Format(i))
      .Min = 0
      .Max = 12
    End With
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry for not giving any words for almost a week now, just had an Easter holiday and just got back to work, will be trying out the code in a bit, thank you.

Comment: thanks you two, I tried mashing your codes together and it's working, thank you.